# Pub folder html file: serving from nginx + CDN and CORS

Tags: magento2, cdn, cors

In my `pub/static` folder I can see that most themes are serving HTML files.

However, these are not specifically handled in the Nginx configuration file.
When serving the full folder from CDN I get CORS issues.

Is it a good idea to allow CORS on HTML files?

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' 'always';
```

Or should I add behavior in my CDN that excludes *.html from being cached in the CDN?

Comment: what do you think yourself?  what is better for security and your shop?

Comment: Well I don’t know what security risk there is in allowing Cors on html, however I understand the benefits of caching)

Answer (score 0):

did you know you can replace `'*'` with your origin?

```
map $http_origin $cors_header {
default "";
"~^(www)?\.yourdomain\.com" "$http_origin";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a CNAME record for my CdN. Should I put the CNAME or the real origin?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164768)

Comment: @Jai hm your comment confusing